# Kafka Logs Cleanup Not happening, Huge File Growth

Tags: apache-kafka

We had set the below configuration: Retention hours as 1, Retention bytes as 150 MB in the server.properties in the Kafka Server(Version: 0.9.0.1). Also modified other settings as given below.

```
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs  
log.retention.hours=1
log.retention.bytes=157286400
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
log.cleaner.enable=true
log.cleanup.policy=delete
```

After checking few days, Size of the Kafka log folder too huge as 13.2 GB. We have seen that Topic Offset getting updated and ignores the Old data but Log File doesnt reduce and has all the Old Data and become too huge. Could you help us to find out why Kafka is not deleting the logs(Physically). Do we need to change any configuration ?

Comment: This issue is happening in windows environment.

Comment: Could you determine which topic partition(s) occupied disks most?

Comment: What I really want to know is if internal topic `__consumer_offsets` occupied most.

Comment: We need to identify why Kafka is not deleting the logs for  above configuration.

Comment: Different topics might have different retention policies, so it'd better to make sure if it's the internal topic that occupied the disk most. If not, a deeper investigation is required.

Comment: I have only one topic, one partition and set Retention hours as 1. After every one hour my offset reflecting properly . But Physical log file is not deleted.

Comment: Was this ever resolved?